# Java GarbageCollection and Collections

Tags: java, collections, garbage-collection

Say I do something like this:

```
List<Stuff> methodA() {
    List<Stuff> all_the_stuff_to_do = new ArrayList<>();
    all_the_stuff_to_do.add(new Stuff("important"));
    all_the_stuff_to_do.add(new Stuff("not important"));
    return all_the_stuff_to_do;
}

List<Stuff> methodB() {
     List<Stuff> important_stuff_to_do = new ArrayList<>();
     Stuff important = methodA().get(0);

     // at this point Stuff("not important") is not reachable anymore
     // since I have no reference to the list that contains it left

     important_stuff_to_do.add(important);  
     return important_stuff_to_do;
}

void methodC() {
     ... do a happydance ...

     List<Stuff> stuff_to_do = methodB();

     ... look sad because now I got important stuff to do ...
}
```

***** EDIT *****
Better clarification and simplified code

To Clarify:

When exiting **methodA()** I got a reference of a list with two objects **Stuff("important")** and **Stuff("not important")**

I add the reference to Stuff("important") to a list in **methodB()**.
At this point the Object **Stuff("not important")** is not reachable anymore.
Also the List in **methodA()** is not reachable anymore.

But the List still contains a reference to an Object that is indeed reachable, namely **Stuff("important")**.

When will the **all_the_stuff_to_do** List be cleared and when the **Stuff("not important")** Object?

Will it be directly after the Call to **MethodA**? Or will it be at the end of **MethodB**? Or never since it contains a reference to the **Stuff("important")**  Object that is still active till the end of the program?

Comment: Which list reference are you referring to? `all_the_stuff_to_do`, `important_stuff_to_do` or `stuff_to_do`?

Comment: What do you mean by "Stuff(2)"? What method are you calling?

Comment: I think you might have meant: `important_stuff_to_do.add(methodA().get(i));` in your for loop in methodB

Comment: In general this code is a bit off.  You are calling methodA mutiple times and each time it's creating a new list and new objects that go into it.  If the point of methodB is simply to return a list that matches methodA, it's unnecessary.  My guess is that you are trying to set up a scenario that you are concerned with but it's not clear what that is.

Comment: @JBNizet i mean Stuff("important"), fixed that in the example

Comment: @JimmyJames I try to figure out when exactly the GC will start collecting the Objects which are not directly referenced to anymore. The code is just an example to illustrate the problem i was thinking about. I edited the text to make it more clear what i mean. And i just mean the objects which have the tag not important. The number in my question was a mistake from the first demo_code i wrote, and was leftover in the question but already renamed in the code

Comment: GC in (normal) JVMs is not caused by de-referencing objects.  It's a result of trying to create new objects and the JVM needing to make room for them.  Whether an object is 'directly referenced' is not important.  It's whether it can be reached from the 'roots' of the VM through any path.  An object can have 1000 references to it but if none of those references are reachable, it's not reachable and eligible for collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will (`all_the_stuff_to_do` be garbage collected) directly after the Call to MethodA? 
>   Or will it be at the end of MethodB? Or never since it contains a reference to the Stuff("important") Object that is still active till the end of the program?

Garbage collection is generally done on a low priority thread.  If nothing else is being done, the garbage collector may run.

If the VM is low on, or out of, memory, the garbage collector may run immediately as the highest priority thread, since it needs to recover memory for the program's immediate need.

So, will it be collected directly after the call to `MethodA`?  No.   Will it get collected after the call to `get(0)`?  Possible, but unlikely.  At the end of `MethodB`?  Possible, but unlikely.  Still active at the end of the program?  Possible, but only likely if the program never ran out of memory and never became idle.

The fact that the list contains a copy of "Stuff("important") Object" is irrelevant to whether the list gets collected.  If no accessible objects reference the list, the list is eligible for garbage collection.

Will the list get `#clear()`'d during collection?  No, there is no need.  If it was a user defined collection, the `clear` method could do anything, including add another reference to the list, which would mess up the garbage collection.  Instead, it is just collected, and objects the list refer to are referenced one less time.  That include "Stuff("important") Object" ... It's reference count will get decremented, but since a reference still exists, it won't be cleared.

Comment: Thanks this is the awnser i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The collection contains references to the objects that you have added.  Until that is no longer reachable or you remove the objects from the collection, they will be reachable.  Can you think of a way programs could work reliably if it were otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario `new Stuff("important")` here `new` keyword is responsible to making an object and reference of this `Stuff` Object hold by the collection `List <Stuff> important_stuff_to_do`. Now this collection will hold the reference of the two object that you made .

As per **Collection** definition all we know that `Collection` is a group of multiple **Object** of same type of **Objects** as a single **Entity**.

So, No `Garbage Collection` will be perform because here these two **objects** are still **reachable**.

```
new Stuff("important")
new Stuff("not important")
```

> Note:- Garbage Collection performs only objects which is completely unreachable (One kind of Orphan). Here No Object is getting orphan because `Collection` never makes the copy / cloing of the objects which is added .

**Conclusion** :- No Garbage will be performed in this scenario. Thank you

Comment: @Vikrant_Kashyap I think i explained too complicated, take a look now, since the problem is that Stuff("not important") is not reachable anymore